# Probability: Reading tables and using the data from them?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Alright probability is not as hard as I imagined yet I strugle with reading tables and applying them to the formulas. The question bellow has a table with 3 rows and 3 collumns and I am asked to see what is the proability of picking an orange. Do I have to add the given three probabilities for it and then apply them in a conditional probability equation or do I have to do something else?

Bellow is the question I am trying to figure out now:
[image: Here]

NB: It is to be noted that my confusion may coms from the way the question is written as almost every question from this particular paper is rather poorly described.

Comment: I do not think this question is poorly described.

Comment: What answer did you get for the first part (you must have managed to do that). The prob of picking an orange is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to answer the first question, "what is the probability of picking an orange?". Let's split this question into three mutually disjoint and exhaustive cases:

1. What is the probability of picking an orange from the red box? The probability of picking the red box to begin with is $0.2$, and after that, the probability of picking an orange is ${}^4/_{10}$, giving a probability of $0.2 \cdot {}^4/_{10} = {}^2/_{25}$.
2. What is the probability of picking an orange from the green box? The probability of picking the green box to begin with is $0.6$, and after that, the probability of picking an orange is ${}^1/_2$, giving a probability of $0.6 \cdot {}^1/_2 = {}^3/_{10}$.
3. What is the probability of picking an orange from the blue box? The probability of picking the blue box to begin with is $0.2$, and after that, the probability of picking an orange is ${}^3/_{10}$, giving a probability of $0.2 \cdot {}^3/_{10} = {}^3/_{50}$.

Summing up these probabilities we get the total probability of picking an orange, ${}^2/_{25} + {}^3/_{10} +  {}^3/_{50} = {}^{11}/_{25} = 44\%$.

The second question requires more careful reasoning, because it is 'conditional probability': given the *condition* that an orange was picked, you want to find the probability of the green box being picked. We can use Bayes' Theorem here ($O$ is the event that the orange is picked, $G$ is the event that the green box is picked):
$$\begin{align}
P(G|O) &= \frac{P(O|G) \cdot P(G)}{P(O)} \\
&= \frac{{}^1/_2 \cdot 0.6}{{}^{11}/_{25}} \\
&= \frac{15}{22} \approx 68\%
\end{align}$$

For the third question, you need to make cases on which box and fruit was chosen in the first choice, and then calculate the probability for each of those cases and add them up as we did for the first question.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you need to condition on whether the fruit is chosen from the red box, the green box, or the blue box and use the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Statement).

For the second question, you wish to find $P(\text{green} \mid\text{orange})$. Here [Bayes' formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Statement_of_theorem) (and your answer from the first question) will be helpful.

For the last question, you need to condition on which box was chosen the fist time, which piece of fruit was chosen, and which box was chosen the second time, and again use the law of total probability.